# public int loses value after an action is completed

Tags: c#, winforms, storage, pass-by-reference

My `int`, which is declared in a seperate class in `dataStorage.cs`, loses its value after this action is done:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataStore dataStore = new dataStore();

    dataStore.position = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);

} // <= right here the value is reset to 0
```

what I am trying to do is, passing values between forms. but when the other form starts its process my `dataStorage.position` loses its value and resets to "0".

How can I properly pass values between forms?

Comment: @Brandon it is position. declared as `public int position = 0;`

Comment: The standard C# naming convention is that methods and classes are PascalCase.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you are creating a local storage variable, which immediately goes out of scope.

Declare it as part of the form class:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public dataStore _dataStore = new dataStore();

    public MyForm() { }

    private void button1_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dataStore.position = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't done anything with `dataStore`. It sounds like you're wanting to set the value of `position` for an instance of `dataStorage` that you're not actually using. You need to set the instance of `dataStorage` to the instance you create in that button for it to retain its value.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is actually expected.
When you instantiate an object, it has scope only in the context it was created in.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataStore dataStore = new dataStore();

    dataStore.position = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);

} // When this function returns, dataStore no longer exists!
```

In this case, your dataStore object only exists inside of the button click handler.

What you want to do is declare the DataStore as a private member of your class, and then assign the value in the click handler.

```
private dataStore dataStore = new dataStore();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataStore.position = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);

} // <= right here the value is reset to 0
```

Also the actual class name in C# should have a capitalized letter for each word (PascalCase), not lowercase first letter followed by capitalized for remaining words (camelCase):

```
class DataStore { }
...
private DataStore dataStore = new DataStore();
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't persist the value in any lasting location.  Here's an explanation of what you're doing:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // You've called a function, in this case a click handler

    // Here you create an instance of `dataStore`
    // This instance exists *only* within the scope of this function
    dataStore dataStore = new dataStore();

    // Here you set a value on that instance
    dataStore.position = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
}
// Now that the function has ended, any variables which were declared
// within the scope of the function are now out of scope, and removed
// from memory.
```

What's not clear from this code is how the value *should* be persisted.  There are many options:

1. Declare the value as static, in which case you don't need to create a new instance.  A static value would be available anywhere in the code.
2. Store the value in some persistence medium, such as a database.  Basically you'd commit your `dataStore` object to persistence and retrieve it somewhere else.
3. Pass your `dataStore` instance as a method argument to whatever you're calling next.
4. Declare `dataStore` as a class-level member for this form and reference it in the other method.

It's *likely* (but, again, we can't know for sure from this code) that you want the fourth option.  Which would look something like this on your form:

```
public class YourForm : Form
{
    private dataStore dataStore = new dataStore();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataStore.position = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
    }

    private void YourOtherMethod()
    {
        // dataStore.position will have a value after the button
        // click handler is executed
    }
}
```

The main point here is to think in terms of object instances.  Think of a class as a "blueprint" for an object.  When you create a `new` object, you're building an instance based on that blueprint.  That instance is now unique in the system, and if you need to access it elsewhere in the code then that instance needs to be passed around the system in some way.

Comment: but i need to pass it between forms as i said. so the private void wont work for this. also when i check the value in dataStore.cs it is back to 0 after the btn click method is completed again.

Comment: @user3002135: How are the forms related to each other?  Where is the second form created/shown?  You can add a `dataStore` to the constructor of the other form, you can expose it as a parameter on this form and add a reference to this form in the other form's constructor, etc.  Can you elaborate in your question and include more code about this other form?  Right now there's only one form in your question.  Also, there is no "value in dataStore.cs", there is a value in the *instance* that was created on this form.